# my Kendo UI project this error taking 'uid' of undefined" when cancel click button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik

I alert taking "Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined" when Cancel Button click. I am using `.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).`

This error's detailed exist below.

I waiting  your reply-solve short time, thanks telerik group.

```
function index(dataItem) {
    var data = $("#StatusGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();
    return data.indexOf(dataItem);
}

public ActionResult EmptyAction(CopyrightContract contract)
    {
        return View("CpContractEdit", contract);
    }

 @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Statusses).Name("StatusGrid")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(p => p.ID).ClientTemplate("#= ID #" +
                          "<input type='hidden' name='Statusses[#= index(data)#].ID' value='#= ID #' />"
                          ).Hidden(true);
                columns.Bound(p => p.STATUSCODE).ClientTemplate("#= STATUSCODE #" +
                          "<input type='hidden' name='Statusses[#= index(data)#].STATUSCODE' value='#= STATUSCODE #' />"
                          ).Width(100);
                columns.Bound(p => p.DESCRIPTION).ClientTemplate("#= DESCRIPTION #" +
                          "<input type='hidden' name='Statusses[#= index(data)#].DESCRIPTION' value='#= DESCRIPTION #' />"
                          );
                columns.Bound(p => p.STATUSDATE).ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(STATUSDATE), 'dd/MM/yyyy') #" +
                       "<input type='hidden' name='Statusses[#= index(data)#].STATUSDATE' value='#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(STATUSDATE), 'dd/MM/yyyy') #' />"
                          ).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}").Width(100);
                columns.Command(command => { command.Destroy().HtmlAttributes(new { title = "Sil" }).Text(" ").IconClass("k-icon k-i-delete k-icon-64"); command.Edit().HtmlAttributes(new { title = "Değiştir" }).UpdateText("Güncelle").Text(" ").CancelText("İptal").IconClass("k-icon k-i-track-changes k-icon-64"); }).Width(124);
            })
            .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("Statü Ekle"))
            .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("statusEdit").Window(w =>
            {
                w.Width(700);
                w.Height(500);
                w.Title("Statü Durumu");
            }))
            .Pageable()
            .Sortable()
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(20)
            .Model(p=>p.Id(model=>model.ID))
            .Create(update => update.Action("EmptyAction", "Contract"))
            .Read(read => read.Action("EmptyAction", "Contract"))
            .Update(update => update.Action("EmptyAction", "Contract"))
            .Destroy(update => update.Action("EmptyAction", "Contract"))
            .ServerOperation(false))
        )
```

Comment: This could be a problem in the dataSource or in an event handler. We need to see some code to be able to help.

Comment: hey @GaloisGirl, codes shared with you now.

Comment: Your CRUD actions make no sense. You should be updating the data and returning Json - not a view.